# Ensure module is loaded after all magento 2 modules

Tags: magento2, module, configuration, sequence

I want to create a module that is loaded first after all the magento modules are loaded. Is there a list somewhere of all them magento 2 module sequence?  Or is there any way to set a module to load first after all magento framework modules?

Comment: There will be custom modules and 3rd party modules loaded after this module.  Meaning it won't be always last, just last after magento 2 framework

Comment: Why do you want this kind of functionality?